# Creating Note System inside QGIS

Tags: qgis

I need to make something similar to a note system, where I can create a feature that will give me something similar to a note system (or a square in the map linked to a feature that will only show itself when editable) where I can type any notes.

The point of this is to correct map details and I have a lot of employees that don't know how to correct them so I need a system in which if they see some errors in the map they will just have to place a feature (or something similar) close to the errors and then specify the errors (so it can then be fixed later on).

There is one more thing, I said that adding a feature combined with a note system would be good because i need to have certain control over the overall notes or features, for example, in case that I need to search for it all at once or edit it all at the same time.

If there is no such thing then maybe a recommended plugin would come in handy.

Answer (score 4):

A possible implementation of such a note system would be to simply introduce a new point layer, where the employees mark a position and describe the problem.

This approach can be fine tuned a lot by building a [custom form](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22458/how-do-i-build-a-custom-form-for-entering-attributes-in-qgis).

You can create fields for error-classes, who reported it, when it was reported, which layer it refers to, when it was solved, active/closed field etc etc.

For most of these fields, you could prepare lists of expected values and make drop-downs etc to speed up entering data (type of error, which layer, which employee etc)

Finally, you can design your own form layout with QTDesigner and assign it to this layer to overcome graphical limitations of the standard forms.

On windows, you'll find that program in your OSGEO4W/bin-folder.