# QGIS- editing form auto completion

Tags: qgis, editing, spatial-join, qfield

I'm new in QGIS world :)

I would like to have an auto-completion script within the editing form on QGiS.
When editing a point features with QGIS form, I would like the script to identify the list of features (polygons) falling under this coordinates and to put their ID in a dedicated field of the feature which is edited.

I have no idea what would be the easiest way to it without reinventing the wheel!

so the steps are : I start the editing of a point feature in the QGIS Form, the script gets the list of polygon features under the coordinates and fills in a myPolygons fields with their IDs...

Comment: You are looking for a spatial join. You can perform it within the field calculator of qgis. I think this will give you an idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMEhdW6rvB4

Comment: Thank you Javier, Yes this works in asynchrone mode for already existing features. what about, whithin the editing action please? that means while i have the new feature editing form open and whenever I reclick again to adjust the feature coordinates.

Comment: Are you using a custom edit form? like this examples? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22459/138363 . If this is the case, maybe it is a good idea to add information on how you are building it and add something like "custom edit form" in the question title.

Comment: Hello Javier Thank you man. Definitly to use the QGIS Native edit form. Spatial joint is the spirit of my need except the fact that it requires a specif action after the editing. It would be great to have a solution working in "real time" while the editing foorm is open. So if any idea rises up it will be great! Many thanks for taking some time helping me!

Comment: Look here https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/